# Workbook opens with data in scientific data type

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion

I have Excel VBA code that extracts data from a .csv and an .xls file. These two files are both of varying file name and path.

When the files opens as a Workbook, the data are already in scientific data type. This change in data type causes errors during extraction and may even lead to wrong data interpretation.

```vb
Sub ExtractData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim SourceFile As Variant
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim wsRs As Worksheet
Dim PTDate As Date, SODate As Date
Dim ProcSteps As Range
Set wsRs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("References")

wsRs.Activate
Set ProcSteps = wsRs.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
Range("M:M, P:P,AA:AA").ColumnWidth = 25
'--------------get prod trackout data--------------
SourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select Production TrackOut File ('FwWeb0101')", Filefilter:="Text Files(*.csv),csv*") 'get filepath
If SourceFile \<\> False Then
Set SourceWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(SourceFile)
Range("A:J").ColumnWidth = 25
Range("A:B,D:D,F:H,K:M,O:R").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Split(Join(Application.Transpose(ProcSteps), ","), ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=wsRs.Cells(1, 10)
SourceWB.Close
'--------------get step output report data--------------
SourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select B800 Step Output Report File ('basenameFwCal0025')", Filefilter:="Excel Files(.xls),*xls*") 'get filepath
If SourceFile \<\> False Then
Set SourceWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(SourceFile)
Range("B:B,D:D,K:N,P:R").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
With ActiveSheet.Sort
.SortFields.Clear
.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Columns("B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Columns("A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
.SetRange Columns("A:J")
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
'-------------------------copy all lots-----------------
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Split(Join(Application.Transpose(ProcSteps), ","), ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=wsRs.Cells(1, 16)
SourceWB.Close
'------------------------check workweek----------------
Else:   MsgBox "No B800 Step Output Report file was selected.", vbCritical ' no file selected
With wsRs.Columns("J:N")
.Clear
.ColumnWidth = 8.11
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Exit Sub
End If
Else:   MsgBox "No Production TrackOut file was selected.", vbCritical ' no file selected
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Exit Sub
End If
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I tried to open the files using the File > Open option of Excel, this gives me the Text to Columns Option.
I tried the Delimiter but with no selected option but the file still opens with scientific data type.

Comment: Do you know the number of digits for the respective numbers displayed in scientific format? Is the number of digits the same for all cases? What format did you try when use 'TextToColumn'? Are there specific columns containing the respective large numbers, or they can be anywhere on the sheet?

Comment: All my data are supposed to be just 10characters. I have sample data, 7822307E03 and this is displayed as 7.82E+09 every time I open the files I need. All these erroneous data are found in one column only. My data are system generated thus I cannot control what my inputs are

Answer (score 0):

In order to oblige Excel showing the (whole) number instead of existing scientific format, you can set a custom `NumberFormat` equal to the respective number number of digits.

If column 7 ("G:G") is the column you intend changing the format and the numeric value has 10 digits, you should simple use:

```
   Columns(7).NumberFormat = "0000000000"
```

If the numeric values in the respective column may have different number of digits, you can proceed in the next way:

```
Sub changeNumform()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
    Const colNo As Long = 7
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastR = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, colNo).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Columns(colNo).EntireColumn.AutoFit: Stop
    For i = 2 To lastR
        ApplyNumFormat ws.cells(i, colNo)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub ApplyNumFormat(c As Range)
  Dim lenNo As Long

   If InStr(c.Text, "E+") > 0 Then 'if in Scientific Format
        lenNo = Len(Split(c.Text, ".")(0)) + CLng(Split(c.Text, "E+")(1))
        c.NumberFormat = String(lenNo, "0")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Princess Danica Serot Didn't you find some time to test the above answer code(s)? If tested, didn't it solve your problem? Even so, some feedback did not kill anybody for such an issue, from what I know...